# Integral combining exponential and hyperbolic function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, closed-form

$\newcommand{\sech}{\operatorname{sech}}$I am solving a larger problem, to which a smaller part is the following improper integral

$$\int\limits_{x}^{\infty}e^{-2\kappa s- s}\sech s\,\mathrm ds\qquad\;\kappa\in(0,1)$$

I am unable to solve it by hand, and MapleSoft for example, doesn't return a closed form expression. I tried the Gradshtein-Ryzhik, table of integrals textbook, in which I found the following elementary form

$$\int e^{ax}\cosh(bx + c)\,\mathrm dx = \frac{e^{ax}}{
a^2 − b^2} [a\cosh(bx + c) − b\sinh(bx + c)]$$

where $a^2\neq b^2,$ but not a combination $e^{ax}\sech(bx)$. Does anyone know, where I might find this integral? Or which software I could use as an alternative.

Comment: For your first integral, are you integrating with respect to $s$ or $x$? If you're integrating with respect to $s$, then $\operatorname{sech} x$ is a constant and can be carried out so you only have the exponential $e^{-2\kappa s-s}$ to deal with

Comment: Presumably, you meant $\operatorname{sech}(s)$. I would try a change of variable $u = e^s$ (or $u = e^{-s}$) to see if that simplifies matters any. Perhaps that will be an integral that can be found in a table of integrals.

Comment: Hint: expand $\operatorname{sech}(x)$ as a geometric series. For $\Re (z)>0$ $$\operatorname{sech}(z)=2e^{-z} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k e^{-2z k}$$

Answer (score 1):

There is an antiderivative in terms of the Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$\int e^{-(2 \kappa +1) s}\, \text{sech}(s)\,ds=-\frac{e^{-2 \kappa  s} }{\kappa}\,\, _2F_1\left(1,-\kappa ;1-\kappa ;-e^{2 s}\right)$$ and for $\kappa\in(0,1)$
$$\int_x^\infty e^{-(2 \kappa +1) s}\, \text{sech}(s)\,ds=\frac{e^{-2 \kappa  x} }{\kappa
   }\, _2F_1\left(1,-\kappa ;1-\kappa ;-e^{2 x}\right)-\pi  \csc (\pi  \kappa )$$

Using the expansion @KStarGamer gave in comments, you will obtain another  Gaussian hypergeometric function.

Comment: I don't have much experience with hypergeometric functions. Do you mean $F_1(1,-\kappa;1-\kappa;-e^{2x})=1-\frac{-\kappa}{1-\kappa}e^{2x}-\frac{2k(1-k)}{(1-k)(2-k)}\frac{e^{4x}}{2}+...$

Comment: also where does $-\pi csc(\pi \kappa)$ come from?

Comment: @dannyt : Yes for the first question. For the second, the value at $\infty$